# NextJS & Prismic - How to prevent /:uid from rendering homepage

Tags: next.js, prismic.io

In the prismic docs the default setup they teach means that your homepage and every other page on your site is the same type.

This means that in that default setup the routes `/` and `/home` both render the homepage.

Is there a way to prevent the `/home` route from rendering, or at least redirect it to `/`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is just with a standard redirect, in your next config:

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects

But there are some other ways that might work, too. For instance, you could add a `if(params.uid === "home") router.push("/")` to pages/[uid].js, to redirect users from `/home` to `/`. (I don't think that code snippet would work, but I hope it illustrates the concept.)

Let me know if you want some other ideas, or if you need help with implementation! I'd be happy to put together a proper example if you need :)

Sam

*Edit: Another option would be to create a singleton "Homepage" Custom Type in Prismic.*